# C# generic string parse to any object

Tags: c#, string, parsing, generics

I am storing object values in strings e.g.,

```
string[] values = new string[] { "213.4", "10", "hello", "MyValue"};
```

is there any way to generically initialize the appropriate object types? e.g., something like

```
double foo1 = AwesomeFunction(values[0]);
int foo2 = AwesomeFunction(values[1]);
string foo3 = AwesomeFunction(values[2]);
MyEnum foo4 = AwesomeFunction(values[3]);
```

where `AwesomeFunction` is the function I need.  The ultimate use is to intialize properties e.g.,

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
PropertyInfo info = typeof(MyObject).GetProperty("SomeProperty");
info.SetValue(obj, AwesomeFunction("20.53"), null);
```

The reason I need such functionality is I am storing said values in a database, and wish to read them out via a query and then initialize the corresponding properties of an object.  Is this going to be possible?  The entire object is not being stored in the database, just a few fields which I'd like to read & set dynamically.  I know I can do it statically, however that will get tedious, hard to maintain, and prone to mistakes with numerous different fields/properties are being read.

EDIT: Bonus points if `AwesomeFunction` can work with custom classes which specify a constructor that takes in a string!

EDIT2: The destination type can be know via the PropertyType, in the specific case where I want to use this type of functionality. I think Enums Would be easy to parse with this e.g.,

```
Type destinationType = info.PropertyType;
Enum.Parse(destinationType, "MyValue");
```

Comment: re "bonus points" - it would be better to define and associate a `TypeConverter`, and have *that* handle this (forwarding to the constructor). Since that is what type-converters are designed for...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Perhaps the first thing to try is:

```
object value = Convert.ChangeType(text, info.PropertyType);
```

However, this doesn't support extensibility via custom types; **if you need that**, how about:

```
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(info.PropertyType);
object value = tc.ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, text);
info.SetValue(obj, value, null);
```

Or:

```
info.SetValue(obj, AwesomeFunction("20.53", info.PropertyType), null);
```

with

```
public object AwesomeFunction(string text, Type type) {
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(type);
    return tc.ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, text);
}
```

Comment: Wow, quick reply!  Looks like this code works a treat.  That TypeConverter class is pretty sweet, pretty much exactly what I was after.  Thanks!

Comment: +1.PS: for OP's edit: If you have some other custom classes besides int/double/etc, you can write a corresponding `TypeConverter`. Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).

Comment: @mrnye - for info, you can write your own type-converters pretty easily - just annotate your custom types with `[TypeConverter(...)]` to tell it what you want. You can *even* change the converters for existing types if you like...

Comment: @Danny - good links, ta. If the type is outside of your control (i.e. you can't add the attribute at source), you can also use `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` to associate a custom converter at runtime.

Comment: @Danny @Marc Thanks, those links are good.  I think I will go down this path and implement a TypeDescriptor for each of my classes (there are only a dozen or so custom classes so is a fairly painless process).  Everything else is Enums or basic classes which all appear to work with this method.

Comment: @Marc This looks perfect for what i need, except... it doesnt look like 'System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor' is supported in Silverlight 4. (which is where i need it)

Answer (score 4):

```
public T Get<T>(string val)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        return (T) TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (T)).ConvertFromString(val);
    else 
        return default(T);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice an explanation on what this code does, instead of just pasting the code

Comment: string parse to any generic

Comment: For those who would like [more than what was provided](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx) on what is going on in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple version:

```
object ConvertToAny(string input)
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out i))
        return i;
    double d;
    if (double.TryParse(input, out d))
        return d;
    return input;
}
```

It will recognize ints and doubles, but everything else is returned as a string. The problem with handling enums is that there's no way to know what enum a value belongs to and there's no way to tell whether it should be a string or not. Other problems are that it doesn't handle dates/times or decimals (how would you distinguish them from doubles?), etc.

If you're willing to change your code like this:

```
PropertyInfo info = typeof(MyObject).GetProperty("SomeProperty"); 
info.SetValue(obj, AwesomeFunction("20.53", info.PropertyType), null);
```

Then it becomes substantially easier:

```
object ConvertToAny(string input, Type target)
{
    // handle common types
    if (target == typeof(int))
        return int.Parse(input);
    if (target == typeof(double))
        return double.Parse(input);
    ...
    // handle enums
    if (target.BaseType == typeof(Enum))
        return Enum.Parse(target, input);
    // handle anything with a static Parse(string) function
    var parse = target.GetMethod("Parse",
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static |
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public,
                    null, new[] { typeof(string) }, null);
    if (parse != null)
        return parse.Invoke(null, new object[] { input });
    // handle types with constructors that take a string
    var constructor = target.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
    if (constructor != null)
        return constructor.Invoke(new object[] { input });
}
```

Edit: Added a missing parenthesis

Comment: And anyway such function (and as your does) will return `object` so OP should cast to some type: `(int)ConvertToAny("1")`. In other words (IMO) - this not possible / the task makes no sense. Only CLR, not C# can contain functions different only by returning type

Comment: See EDIT2 for additional info.  In my specific use, I can get the destination class type via the PropertyType property.  This would make parsing Enums simple.  It would also make it possible to differentiate between floats/doubles/decimals/etc.  However, I was hoping to avoid writing a big if/case statement for each class type (although I guess it wouldn't be **that** messy).

Comment: myrne: Marc's answer might still be better, but I modified mine to support enums, constructors that take a string, and anything with a Parse function.

Comment: Yes, yours does look much neater now.  Both will work, although Marc's is a bit neater imo.  The only thing I am wondering now is whether either method would be significantly slower than the other.  I do not think speed will be much of an issue (unless it's taking seconds rather than milliseconds) but it would be interesting to know.  I will have to run some tests.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your question, but have you looked at [Dapper micro ORM](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)?
It's über-simple (compared to LINQ to SQL or, for that reason, Entity Framework) and does what you want.

Consider this:

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }    
}            

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select * from Dogs where Id = @Id",
    new { Id = 42 }
).First();
```

Dapper itself is packaged in a [single file](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) and, reportedly, [is used by StackOverflow team](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dapper/info) (apart from Linq to SQL).