# Constraint which force generic parameter to be parseable from string

Tags: c#, constraints, generics

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965871/c-generic-string-parse-to-any-object) topic one can find solution to make generic class which provides parsing from string to generic parameter type. However, it could happen that type given to this parameter does not provide such conversion. Is there a way to make constraint assuring that?

UPDATE:
Thank you for your answers. However I know I can generally make constraints. The problem is: is there any interface that all types, which Convert.ChangeType won't fail at, implements. Or which is implemented by all types with Parse(string) method.

Comment: There are two problems here: one is that you can't add interfaces to existing types and you can't use duck-typing for generic constraints.  This is going to make it hard to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, as I said in my comment, you can't add interfaces to specific types nor can you use duck-typing in generic type constraints, you'll probably have to end up writing a bit of a hacky solution.  I think your best bet is to make several overloads of your parsing function, one for each of the basic types (int, char, string, etc.) and then provide a generic one that has IConvertible as its generic constraint.  The compiler will choose the right overload, or none at all in the case of non-convertible types.

Comment: Thought maybe there already exists desired interface. Regardless, thats' the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski: alas, no.  The base class library is actually kind of poorly designed.  Ideally, every core operation or set of operations would have an interface associated with it and the base types would implement these interfaces.

Comment: Can you expand a little on the overloads? I'm having a hard time picturing how this works with the compiler choosing the right overload.

Comment: @MikeCole: the compiler will always pick the more specific overload over the more generic one. So if you have a `Parse(int arg)` and a `Parse<T>(T arg)`, and you call `Parse(3)`, it will call the first overload, not the second, even though the second does technically accept integers (there are no type constraints forbidding it). I'm not sure, 5 years later, why the overloads are necessary. `int`, `char`, etc. all implement `IConvertible`. But assuming that's not acceptable as an argument type for the original question, then you would have to have a generic overload and then the specific ones.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [Type Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to restrict what types of objects can be used in the generic class. You should define an interface that can be used to do that conversion and than set that interface as the constraint.